# Special UnknownHostException with machine name

Tags: java, android, exception, dns

I get an `UnknownHostException` (from `lookuphostbyname`).

Doing this:

```
result = httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
```

I have the internet permission and internet access.

AND: If I use the ip it works.
If I use http://www.google.de it works.

But if I use the machine name in the URL it doesn't...
How can this be? Does android/java do not handle machine names?

I also tried:

```
InetAddress i = InetAddress.getByName(URLName);
```

I don't know that I can do next...

Edit: With the fqdn it work's. But machine names dont?

Comment: using the fqdn works. but is there no chance to use machine names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify a few things.

If you are using the emulator it can be considered exactly the same as using a separate device.

By this, any network requests will be treated as NOT coming from your PC.

While I believe it is possible to get into the device/emulator and add a host record, its not a path you really want to go down.

Best bet is to just use IP address or always make sure the address you are using are in a DNS that is accessible from the device/emulator (doesn't need to be a public one).

Basically think of the emulator/device as a separate computer and you will know where you need to go

Answer (score 0):

The machine name must either be registered in a DNS that this machine can see, or it needs to be resolved in your hosts file.

Comment: How can i register it in a DNS? Using windows (e.g. ping) it works in this network... The hosts file is an option but I do not want to edit this file of all my users ;-)